# How to run thread in Main with DispatchTime in for Loop swift

Tags: swift, multithreading, for-loop, nsdate, background-thread

I have doubt for the run thread with time delay
Dispatch is not enter to after finished the time?

```
 for i in 0...10000 {
      let deadLine = DispatchTime.now() + .milliseconds(1000)
      DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: deadLine) {
        print(i)
      }
    }
```

Anyone have done this before?
Thanks.

Comment: Why are you try this? What do you want to do with this lines? Maybe we can find another way

Answer (score 1):

The for loop doesn't wait, it is executed in the main thread. `DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter` doesn't block the main thread, all it does is queue a block of code to be executed after certain time. Queuing the printing of `i` is done at almost the same time, maybe spaced in time by a few microseconds if not nanoseconds.

Instead of trying to block the main thread, you could use the `Timer` API :

```
//In a playground
var timer: Timer? = nil
var counter = 0

timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: 1.0, repeats: true) { _ in
    print("\(counter)\t\(Date())")

    if counter == 10 {
        timer?.invalidate()
    }

    counter += 1
}

timer?.fire()
```

Which would print for example:

> ```
> 0   2019-08-19 20:19:36 +0000
> 1   2019-08-19 20:19:37 +0000
> 2   2019-08-19 20:19:38 +0000
> 3   2019-08-19 20:19:39 +0000
> 4   2019-08-19 20:19:40 +0000
> 5   2019-08-19 20:19:41 +0000
> 6   2019-08-19 20:19:42 +0000
> 7   2019-08-19 20:19:43 +0000
> 8   2019-08-19 20:19:44 +0000
> 9   2019-08-19 20:19:45 +0000
> 10  2019-08-19 20:19:46 +0000
> ```